# vagrant-winnfsd composer could not delete error

Tags: vagrant, composer-php

While using Vagrant + winNFSD + Virtualbox, `composer update` fails due to the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /vendor/symfony/symfony/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_hbnOON:
```

When trying to delete the file manually via `rm vendor/symfony/symfony/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_hbnOON`, I get the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘vendor/symfony/symfony/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_hbnOON’: Input/output error
```

The issue is with the winnfsd plugin, as discussed in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd/issues/22). Unfortunatly, the fixes proposed in the thread do not work. Is there currently a solution to this problem (I'm using vagrant-winnfsd 1.0.11)